# can c++ store this? template <typename T> (store the typename T so I can reuse it later?)

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Item {
public:
  T item;
  void* ptr = nullptr;
  Item(T var): item(var) {}

  unknown next(){
    if ((unknown*)ptr != nullptr){
      std::cout<<"It is not a null pointer!"<<std::endl;
      return (unkown*)ptr
    }else{
      std::cout<<"It is a null pointer..."<<std::endl;
      return NULL
    }
  }

  template <typename temp>
  void pass(temp *var){
    ptr = var;
  }
};

int main() { 
  Item<int> i(100);
  Item<float> n(200.0);
  i.pass(&n);
  i.next();
}
```

My problem is to "remember" the type `T` so I can replace `unknown`.

I need the `void*` pointer to point to an unknown type, and I need to type-cast to the **right type** to retrieve what I stored in it.  When the `Item` was created, nothing was registered (nothing should be registered).

If somehow you guys know how to do that, is it possible to also change the type "remembered" during compile time?

Comment: I assume you want to replace `unknown` with `temp`, not with `T`? That's not possible.

Comment: What keeps you from using `T` in all places of `unknown`? After fixing several mistakes (missing `;` and `*`) your code then compiles and outputs "It is not a null pointer!". I do not see your problem as long as you are not trying to use `T` from outside of the class. And even then there is an obvious solution.

Comment: The only time `void *` should be used in C++ code is for interfacing with a C library API. There is never a need to use `void *` in well-designed C++ code, for anything.

Answer (score 1):

`pass` as a template could receive an infinite number of types, while the return type of `next` is fixed to a single type. You are asking for a way to treat all types as a single type, and unfortunately `void*` is the only way to go; you cannot recover the type used in `pass`.

I'm not 100% certain of what all your use cases of this class are, so I'll describe a few type-erasure techniques you should look into:

- Consider using a `std::variant` and putting the onus of what to do with the contained type into a visitor defined by the user. e.g., `Item<int, double>` stores a `variant<int, double>`
- Alternatively, use a `std::any` and put the onus of recovering type information onto the caller.
- Alternatively, enforce type-erasure via polymorphism; instead of `void*`, own a pointer to a base class.
- Another type-erasure approach is Sean Parent's ["run time polymorphism" approach](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2017-01-18-runtime-polymorphism/2017-01-18-runtime-polymorphism.pdf), where the user provides an implementation of the required behavior as a function that can be discovered through [Argument-Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). Via *internal-only polymorphism*, you can call the appropriate function for the contained pointer (not too different from how `std::function` is implemented).